# keep string between two words node js express javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, express

I have a string like:

```
var str = put returns between paragraphs abc_start indent code by 4 spaces abc_end quote by placing > at start of line abc_start  to make links abc_end.
```

I'm displaying this string in my browser using:

```
res.send('/page/+result);
```

I want to filter out result such that only the content which starts at abc_start and end at abc_end remains. How do I do that in node.js?

For eg: output:
**abc_start** indent code by 4 spaces **abc_end** **abc_start** to make links **abc_end**

I tried using : `str.split('abc_start').pop().split('abc_end').shift();`

But I'm not gettting desired output.Please help.

Comment: Can you give another short example? Not sure what you want to do

Comment: Keep only the content between abc_start and abc_end, check the edits

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "abc_start indent code by 4 spaces abc_end";
    var n = str.indexOf("abc_start ");
    var m = str.indexOf("abc_end");
    var res = str.slice(n+9, m-1);//Since you already know the length of the string "abc_start" that you want out of the way
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

Comment: abc_start and abc_end can be present multiple times

Comment: Samples would be a great way of clarifying the ambiguity of your issue.
Moreover i feel you can play around the above answer to achieve your results, but feel free to post supporting samples let's know what the bug is

Comment: sample : var str = put returns between paragraphs abc_start indent code by 4 spaces abc_end quote by placing > at start of line abc_start  to make links abc_end.

Comment: In the event of multiple occurrences of abc_start and abc_end it may be worth your time to tokenize the strings using the split function, then traverse the string from the first occurrences of abc_start and capture all input until abc_end followed by another occurrence of abc_start till abc_end

Answer (score 0):

Below is code snippet to solve this scenario:

```
var str = 'xxxadasyyydsdsxxxadadyyy';
var start = 'xxx';
var end = 'yyy'
var res = [];
find();
function find() {
    var initialIndex = str.indexOf(start);
    var lastIndex = str.indexOf(end);
    if(initialIndex > -1 && lastIndex > -1 && initialIndex < lastIndex) {
        res.push(str.substring(initialIndex, lastIndex + start.length));
        str = str.substring(lastIndex + start.length);
        find();
    } else {
        return;
    } 
}
console.log(res);
```